# Issue with loading thread participants using Symfony FosMessageBundle or OrnicarMessageBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to provide messeging features in my project on symfony with FosMessageBundle.

Following documentation I use this string of code to load all inbox threads.

```
$provider = $this->container->get('fos_message.provider');
$threads = $provider->getInboxThreads();
```

The result of dump of each thread in twig is:

```
Thread {#1300 ▼
  #id: 7
  #createdBy: User {#1129 ▶}
  #messages: PersistentCollection {#1294 ▶}
  #metadata: PersistentCollection {#1273 ▶}
  #participants: null
  #keywords: ""
  #createdAt: DateTime {#1311 ▶}
  #subject: "First msg"
  #isSpam: false
}
```

My problem is how to get participants of each thread?

Of Course I can get participants if I load single thread. But using methods getInboxThreads() or getSentThreads() property participants is null.

Please, let my know if you have solution of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate threads like:

```
   $provider = $this->container->get('fos_message.provider');
   $threads = $provider->getInboxThreads();
   foreach($threads as $thread)
   {
        foreach ($thread->getParticipants() as $participant)
        {
            // here is your thread participant is $participant
        }
   }
```

Hope you want this result.